# Masonite - What is the difference between "name" and "prefix" when making route groups

Tags: python, frameworks, masonite

I have this code snippet but I am not sure what the difference between `prefix` and `name` is in the group parameters?

```
group([
    #Get().route('/', 'WelcomeController@show').name('welcome'),
    get('/', 'PostController@show').name('form'),
    post('/store', 'PostController@store').name('create')
], prefix='blog.', name="blog."])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prefix is actually the prefix to the route itself and `name` just prepends the name to the names of all routes inside the group.

Take this for example:

```
group([
  get('', 'PostController@show').name('form'),
  get('/create', 'PostController@create').name('create'),
], prefix='/blog', name="blog."])
```

what this snippet does is creates two routes to match the URL's of `/blog` and `/blog/create` but also prepends the names to the routes such as `blog.form` and `blog.create`

The names of the routes can be used for redirection:

```
def show(self, request: Request):
    request.redirect_to('blog.create') #== /blog/create
```

or generating urls like this:

```
<a href="{{ route('blog.create') }}">Link</a>
```

which generates the same URL as above.